# What is wrong with the following Hybridizer code using ResidentArrayGeneric?

Tags: c#, hybridizer

The following code extracts a square selection from an (image) array of floats and places it in an array of float2. Both the float2 and original arrays are 1D arrays that represent successive rows in the image. The original float value is placed in the x field and the y field is set to zero.
The code below is failing to compile using Hybridizer and I have no idea why.
One of the errors is:-

> 'no suitable constructor exists to convert from "float" to "float2" '
>   line 32

which is the line for the closing bracket of the kernel.
 I am not directly converting from float to float2 so i am confused!

Does anyone one have any idea what is wrong?

```
using Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports;
using System;

namespace residentarraytest
{

    class Program
    {
        [EntryPoint]
        private static void ExtractArea(FloatResidentArray im,
                                ResidentArrayGeneric<int> roi,
                                ResidentArrayGeneric<float2> res)
        {
            int cp = roi[2] / 2;
            int yPos = (1024 - roi[1]) - cp; // Y reversal just because...
            int xPos = roi[0] - cp;
            ExtractLoop(im, res, roi[2], yPos, xPos);
            return;
        }

        [Kernel]
        private static void ExtractLoop(FloatResidentArray im,
                                   ResidentArrayGeneric<float2> res, 
                                   int size, int yPos, int xPos)
        {
            Parallel2D.For(0, size, 0, size, (y, x) =>
            {
                int i = x + y * size;
                int j = x + xPos + (y + yPos) * size;
                float2 tmp = new float2(im[j], 0f);                
                res[i] = tmp;
            });
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ResidentArrayGeneric<int> roi = new ResidentArrayGeneric<int>(3);
            roi[0] = 512; roi[1] = 512; roi[2] = 256;
            FloatResidentArray im = new FloatResidentArray(1024 * 1024);
            // im is filled with data here;

            ResidentArrayGeneric<float2> res = 
                new ResidentArrayGeneric<float2>(roi[2] * roi[2]);

            cudaDeviceProp prop;
            cuda.GetDeviceProperties(out prop, 0);            

            HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda();

            // create a wrapper object to call GPU methods instead of C#
            dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new Program());

            roi.RefreshDevice();
            im.RefreshDevice();
            res.RefreshDevice();
            wrapped.ExtractArea(im, roi, res);

            // program continues
            Console.Out.WriteLine("DONE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing is wrong with your code. It's a plain hybridizer bug (in the cuda interface).

I logged an issue into Altimesh [github](https://github.com/altimesh/hybridizer-basic-samples/issues/84).

float2 type (which is an internal driver type) has no constructor taking float as argument. You can have a look at the [CUDA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#vector-types).

Therefore the C# constructor float2::float2(x, y) should not be exposed.

We will expose the function `make_float2` with next release.

In the meantime, you can do it yourself with the following code :

```
[IntrinsicFunction("make_float2")]
public static float2 make_float2(float x, float y)
{
    return new float2(x, y);
}

[Kernel]
private static void ExtractLoop(FloatResidentArray im,
                           ResidentArrayGeneric<float2> res,
                           int size, int yPos, int xPos)
{
    Parallel2D.For(0, size, 0, size, (y, x) =>
    {
        int i = x + y * size;
        int j = x + xPos + (y + yPos) * size;
        float2 tmp = make_float2(im[j], 0f);
        res[i] = tmp;
    });
}
```